# How unable to run pipenv install due to python version incompatibility

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I imported a python folder that came with Pipfile and Pifile.lock in it. I tried to run pipenv install in my VScode terminal window but I got a warning saying: "Warning: Python 3.9 was not found on your system...
Neither 'pyenv' nor 'asdf' could be found to install Python".

I was expecting pipenv install to install the application dependencies and then create a virtual environment which I can go into using pipenv shell. But all to no avail.
In my machine, I have python 3.11.4. Would downgrading the version of my machine to python 3.9 solve the problem? or is there a better way to go about this?
Looking forward to your assistance.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Managing Multiple Python Versions with pyenv**

**`pyenv`** is a powerful tool that allows you to easily manage multiple Python versions on various operating systems, including Windows. You have two installation options:

1. **Manual Installation**

   - Follow this **[guide](https://k0nze.dev/posts/install-pyenv-venv-vscode/)** for step-by-step instructions on installing pyenv on Windows.
2. **Using Chocolatey**

   - First, ensure Chocolatey is installed on your system **[choco](https://chocolatey.org/install)**.
   - Install pyenv with the command: `choco install pyenv-win`.

Keep in mind that the manual installation method is preferred to avoid potential compatibility issues.

**Using Python 3.9.x with pyenv**

Once pyenv is successfully installed, you can add Python 3.9 to any desired folder by running the command:

```
pyenv local 3.9.x
```

This command will ensure that Python 3.9 is isolated and active only within that specific folder, giving you greater flexibility in managing your Python environments.